# Regex with 'OR' condition for dataTables for global search

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

I want to alter the global search for dataTables to handle the 'OR' condition

I can get the 'OR' condition working for a specified column using

```
$('#searchBox').keyup( function(e) {

        if(e.keyCode==13){
            var arr = $('#searchBox').val().split(' ');
            var pattern = (arr[0]) + '|' + (arr[1]);
            oTable.fnFilter(pattern, 1, true);
        }
    } );
```

This will enable the search results for column 1 show both first and second word results. How do I achieve the same for all columns?

Comment: By leaving out the column restriction: oTable.fnFilter(pattern, null, true); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply define the column as `null` :

```
$('#searchBox').keyup( function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){
      var arr = $('#searchBox').val().split(' ');
      var pattern = (arr[0]) + '|' + (arr[1]);
      oTable.fnFilter(pattern, null, false);
   }
});
```

See fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9UtVw/**
- and the `fnFilter` documentation -> **http://www.datatables.net/ref#fnFilter**

Note that columns are zero based. In your code above you sort on the second column (just if you were not aware of it).

---

**Update**. I would also make some array checking. You assume that there is entered a string with white space, like `a b`. But what if there is not, then `|` should not be used, besides  you end up searching after `undefined`. And what if there is entered more than two whice space separated search criterias like `a b c d`?

```
$('#searchBox').keyup( function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){
      var arr = $('#searchBox').val().split(' ');
      var pattern ='';  
      arr.forEach(function(item) {
          if (pattern!='') pattern+='|';
          pattern+=item;
      });
      oTable.fnFilter(pattern, null, true, false, true, true);
   }
});
```

fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/stbRt/**

Comment: Try searching for "Gecko PSP" . Only results for Gecko show up. Also what I have noticed is that oTable.fnFilter(pattern, null, true) works well only for the column 0 and not for any other subsequent columns

Comment: @user544079, Oops! But funny enough the opposit, "PSP Gecko", worked. Appearently the "smart filtering", the forth argument, is not so smart :) It must be turned of (false) - is true by default. Updated the answer and the last jsfiddle. Hope this solve your issues!